# How do I stop a Java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to know how to stop thread in this program:

```
public class MasterServerThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket = null;
private MasterServer server = null;
private int clientID = -1;
private BufferedReader streamInput  = null;
private PrintWriter streamOutput = null;

public MasterServerThread(MasterServer _server, Socket _socket){
    server = _server;
    socket = _socket;
    clientID = _socket.getPort();
}

public void run(){
    server.Log("Server Thread " +clientID + " running");
    while(true){
        String test;
        try {
            test = streamInput.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client "+clientID+": "+test);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(clientID+ " Error reading: "+e.getMessage());
        }
            server.handleClient(clientID, "test");

    }
}
}
```

This is my server thread code. When my client terminates itself, I get an endless loop of errors:

> 53088 Error reading: Connection reset 0

I know something needs to be done here, but I don't know what, exactly:

```
      try {
        test = streamInput.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client "+clientID+": "+test);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(clientID+ " Error reading: "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Amazing, that while (true) loop actually runs forever ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle your `IOException` better and just return (or break) out of the `while(true)` loop.  I'm not sure there is any case that you want to continue to run reading from an `BufferedReader` after it threw such an exception.

```
try {
     test = streamInput.readLine();
     System.out.println("Client "+clientID+": "+test);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println(clientID+ " Error reading: "+e.getMessage());
     // you need the return line here -- or a break
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of connection reset your best bet is just to return from `run` method, this will stop a thread.